# LDAP search user in nested groups with subdomains

Tags: search, nested, ldap, subdomain

I have to check if a user is a member of an nested group within a subdomain.

LDAP setup.

```
MasterGroup -> Domain company.biz
Group1 -> Member of Mastergroup -> Domain sub.company.biz
User1 -> Member of Group1
```

**I know the MasterGroup and the User1.**

How do I check whether the user is a (nested) member of the MasterGroup or not?

Atm I have the following query which is not working.

```
(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=<User1sAMAccountName>)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=<distinguishedName of MasterGroup>))
```

The same request for the Group1 is working and I assume that is because of the subdomain.

```
(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=<User1sAMAccountName>)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=<distinguishedName of Group1>))
```

This returns the user.

*Question: Is there any way to trigger the subdomain search?*

One tip I found on the internet is to search all the subdomains one by one for every group i have to check.
This means I have to send over 256.000 requests...

Thanks in advance.